# Investing in town and resource nodes - what do they do?

Tags: black-desert-online

There are 3 main type of nodes in Black Desert Online:

1. Grind nodes
2. Resource nodes
3. Towns

Investing in grind nodes is clear what it does (increase drop chance by x% depending on lvl). You can get this info from invest button tooltip.

But what does it to for others? I'm assuming that since the button is there there is an use for it.

I've read multiple forums/theories regarding what it does but nothing conclusive. Also tested some myself but because of rng gains is really hard to test alone (would need like 2-3 years to test by myself and get some clear results).

Some theories are:

- For resource nodes it increases the number and/or quality of gained items (Tested myself on 2 nodes but results where inconclusive - I got indeed an increase of like 10% between a lvl 1 node vs a lvl 10, but it may as well be rng, worker level, etc. Also since the period was over 2 months I may have loose track of some of the items).
- For towns it gives you better amity game odds for all npcs in town.
- For towns it decreases the amount of amity you loose when you buy from amity shops.
- For towns it increases the odds for lucky crafts (lucky tools, superior gear, etc.).
- There are some other but from what I tested those were not valid (feel free to add to the list).

None of the things listed here were confirmed/invalidated by me or any resource I found.

The question is: what does investing in towns and resource nodes do? The answer should have an official or reliable source OR should be backed up by testing data.

Comment: I specifically took out theories and answer requirements because they don't do anything but distract readers from the problem.  Requiring answerers to adhere to specific requirements also doesn't work, and one of those requirements is specifically off-topic.

Comment: First sorry if I offended you, ty for trying to improve the question. Second, those requirements are there for a reason, not to mention that they may give other users a starting point for research. I would like the question to remain as it is if you don't mind, even if we don't get an answer (considering the game it probably won't) and/or gets minuses.

Comment: I'm just trying to help clarify what the actual question is.  Potential theories just distract from trying to find the answer, and trying to set requirements for an answer doesn't mean anyone has to abide by them.  In fact, one of your requirements would make the question off-topic, and I can easily see the question being closed for that reason alone.  If you want an answer, I'd highly recommend condensing it and getting to the core question.  How people might answer isn't anything that belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Towns nodes are for the amity game with NPC. Which that in itself gives you a bonus if you have high amity with every NPC in a certain territory. To check this open up the map(M) and look at the shield of a territory right under where it shows what guild currently owns the territory is your 'fame'. 
Grind nodes are for 35% better/higher drop rates from mobs you kill in the area. But the drop rate bonus is only applied 10% of the time. so basically rng within rng. 
And Resource nodes are so you have a higher chance at getting by-product items. For example 'Abandoned Iron Mine' produces Iron Ores and Powder of Darkness with the *chance* of also obtaining Rough Black Crystal which is very important for Alchemy. 
There are other speculations but most people base their nodes investments on these ideals.